# ActiveReports Server - JSON data source with URL parameters for paging and filtering

Tags: c#, json, activereports

I am evaluating ActiveReports Server (ad-hoc) for my reporting related development. I couldn't find example related to JSON data source, more over my paging and filtering is done via URL query string parameters, so how can even that be handled? As I can see that means I have change the data-url of the report at execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveReports Server does not support JSON datasource at this time.  We will look into the scope and feasibility of adding this in a future version release.